# Using Powershell to monitor running applications

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script that needs to know when a program has been opened (Internet Explorer).
Is there a way to run powershell scripts such that you can monitor running programs? Or do I have to run my program as a service?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can use [Register-WMIEvent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849840.aspx).  After you register the event, it will execute an arbitrary [scriptblock](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847893.aspx) if you specify one in the `Action` parameter.

Here's a simple example where the scriptblock only writes to the console whenever a process named `iexpore.exe` is created:

```
Register-WMIEvent -query "Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent within 3 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' and TargetInstance.Name ='iexplore.exe'" `
-sourceIdentifier "New IE Process" `
-action {Write-Host "A new Internet Explorer process has started!"}
```

Here's a helpful [Scripting Guy post concerning Event Monitoring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730927.aspx), if you're interested in reading further. Beware that `Get-PSEvent` is now known as `Get-Event`.